# ¿Cómo crear objetos en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: java, array, poo, arraylist, matriz

Cómo podría crear una matriz en tiempo de ejecución, tipo que el usuario decida la cantidad de matrices a exister, sé que debo crear un método de matriz, estoy intentando con

```
public void Matriz() {
   Matriz = new int[2][2]
}
```

Pero no logro que funcione, no sé si estoy haciendo mal la creación del objeto o no.

Comment: Hola. Para esta y futuras oportunidades: "no logro que funcione" no nos dice mayor cosa. Sé más preciso diciendo qué error sale, qué pasa al correr el código, qué debería pasar, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Faltaba un punto y coma y la declaración de la matriz. Recuerda que java es un lenguaje fuertemente tipado por lo cual antes de declarar una variable debemos declarar de qué tipo es.

La siguiente sería la forma correcta

```
public void Matriz() {
   int[][] Matriz = new int[2][2];
   // resto del código
}
```

Aunque no es muy recomendable

1. Tener un método nombrado con **PascalCase** pues no es el estándar en Java.
2. Tener una variable local cuyo nombre sea el mismo nombre del método pues puede hacer más difícil de leer el código.